# How to do nested mapping with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an entity and model defined as this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }   
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
    public Location Location { get; set; }            
    public string Gender { get; set; }    
    public string Skills { get; set; }    
    public bool isPrivate { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public bool isPrivate { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have setup a mapping profile defined as this:

```
public MappingProfile()
{
    CreateMap<User, UserModel>()
        .ReverseMap();
}
```

And the point is that this works to some extend, but the `Location` complex type is not mapped properly. I can always flatten it, by including `LocationCity` and `LocationCountry` inside the `UserModel` class, but that's not what I wanna do. I want `Location` to appear as a nested property in the returned result, as it is defined originally. How can I achieve this in AutoMapper?

Comment: Does "not mapped properly" mean `null`?

Comment: @aaron exactly, it is null.

Comment: No repro on http://dotnetfiddle.net/OYUEVV

Comment: @aaron Yes, but that is similar to flattening, it won't let me do something like `.ForMember(dest => dest.Location.City, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Location.City))`, so I cannot map the child items.

Comment: You don't need custom mapping. Your example works as-is.

Comment: You *could* use `.ForPath`, but that's wholly unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a mapping between Location to Location too. Yep, the source and destination are identitic.

So your mapping profile should look like this:

```
public MappingProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Location, Location>();
    CreateMap<User, UserModel>()
        .ReverseMap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your configuration like this:

```
 CreateMap<User, UserModel>()
     .ForMember(um => um.Location , opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.Location))
     .ReverseMap();
```

The `ReverseMap` can only create a simple mapping. For any complex type, you need to configure it manually, because AutoMaper don't know exactly how to instantiate the `Location` property and it will return `null` reference.